# After a heavy operation (50,000,000 iterations) free disk space extremely decreased

Tags: c#, windows-7, window, benchmarking

I developed an benchmark-style console application (C# 4.0). Worked fine with 50,000 or 1,000,000 iterations. Then I increased a iteration count to 50,000,000. But it took too much time, and I forced it to quit. The application quitted normally, but in my main drive (C:) remained only 3.8 GB available. Before the testing free space was 14 GB. There's 10 GB has been ate !!! Please, can anybody explain why this happened?

Hi All,

I found that *.vsp file on my project directory (9 GB !!!). Yes, it may seem to be silly, because I looked up for every system|hidden folder on my main drive, but never I thought this giant file may be in my project folder. After the 50,000,000 iterations, I felt that my system got slower, and I ran Performance Wizard in VS2010. But iteration count was very little, so I did not think that performance wizard can create such a giant file! Thanks to all!

Comment: What did you do inside the iteration?

Comment: Performed string operations (with StringBuilder). Also used Stopwatch for retrieving execution time.

Comment: try to search for new files on the system, you may be able to find a large file. Sounds like it may be crash dump file that got saved somewhere. See if this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk551230.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without more information (like what the test actually does) my guess is that the program leaked memory like a sieve, and Windows compensated by steadily increasing the size of the swap/paging file, eating up your hard disk space in the process.  You might take a look at your `C:\pagefile.sys` and see how big it is.

Comment: Actually, the test was about strings. Only string operations and Stopwatch used.

Comment: Did you keep all of the references around somewhere?  Perhaps your test does logging?  Maybe use [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) to see where all the space went?

Comment: Nope, test does not include any IO operations. Only string operations (more correctly, StringBuilder.Append() method) were implemented.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion helped: WinDirStat. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the why - it could depend on your string operations (for example performing concatenation vs. using StringBuilder).

As for where the space is, as stated before it's likely to be your page file.

If it is your page file, the way to reclaim the space is to manually adjust the size of the page file to a much lower than current value via Windows and then reboot.

Windows key + Pause/Break, click Advanced System Settings,  under Performance, click Settings...
In the resulting Performance Options window, under Virtual memory, click Change... Tell Windows to stop automatically managing paging file size. Click on C: drive and set it to a custom size significantly smaller than it is now (try 1024MB for example).

Reboot your machine and the pagefile should now be smaller. Until you restart, the space will still be in use.

You'll probably want to set the paging file size back to being automatically managed by Windows once done.

If you'd like some help in avoiding the code causing the same problem, you might need to provide some code snippets.

Comment: Changing the pagefile size? I'm assuming you'll make the change just prior to the restart, in which case no, you won't notice any performance difference. This is on the assumption that you set it back to being automatically managed afterwards. You'll only notice a performance impact of having a small pagefile if you keep it at that size i.e. don't let Windows control it again. This is something very following-the-book and should not cause any problems for you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's because virtual memory swap page increased, because GC was not running in your iteration loop and the memory usage increasing and then eventually memory got swapped to page file. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828988 for more information about GC in console application. I never tried that but I think using `MTAThread` attribute would help.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary Files of Swap Space (Virtual Memory).

Does your app create files? How much memory does it use (Task manager)?

Comment: Sorry, I did not remember. I think it did not get too much memory. But I remember it was using 1,700,000 cycles after 2-3 mins (Process Explorer, process properties window, .NET tab)